# Given a point R on an Elliptic curve find two distinct points P and Q so that (a) P+Q=R and (b) the y coordinate is the same for P, Q and R

Tags: elliptic-curves

Point addition on elliptic curves allows us to determine a point `R` given two distinct points `P` and `Q` so that `P + Q = R`. There are various ways to calculate point addition depending on the type of curve. A brief explanation of point addition is given [here](https://www.certicom.com/content/certicom/en/21-elliptic-curve-addition-a-geometric-approach.html).

My question looks at the opposite path. Given a point `R(x,y)` on a curve, find two distinct points `P(x,y)` and `Q(x,y)` so that (a) `P(x,y) + Q(x,y) = R(x,y)` and (b) the `y` value is the same for each point P, Q and R.

Is it possible? If not, why not?

The answer can be exemplified using the Secp256k1 curve to limit the scope.

Thanks.

Comment: For the common Weierstrass form affine Elliptic curve of the form
$$
x^3+ax+b = y^2
$$
having a fixed $y$ means a solution to
$$
x^3+ax+c = 0
$$
where $c=b-y^2$. This can have exactly $3$ different roots so the points can exist. However the addition condition can only be satisfied if $2y=0$. This forces $y=0$ unless the ground field has characteristic $2$ (I think some non-zero $y$ may be possible there for characteristic $2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one example for non-zero $y$: Let the degree $3$ finite field $K$ of characteristic $2$ be
$$
K:= \mathbb Z[a]/(2,a^3+a+1)
$$
and consider the following Elliptic Curve $E$ over $K$
$$
E:y^2+xy+y=x^3+x+a
$$
Then there are three points
$$
\begin{align*}
P&=(a,a^2+a),& Q&=(a+1,a^2+a), & R&=(1,a^2+a)
\end{align*}
$$
on $E$ and we may verify that
$$
P+Q=R
$$

---

The line $PQ$ is by definition $y=a^2+a$ with gradient $\lambda = 0$ and constant $v=a^2+a$. The $x$-coordinate of $R$ is given by
$$
x_R=\lambda^2+a_1\lambda-a_2-x_P-x_Q = -x_P-x_Q= -(a)-(a+1) \equiv 1 \pmod 2
$$
The $y$-coordinates of $R$ is
$$
y_R = -(\lambda+a_1)x_3-v-a_3=-(0+1)(1)-(a^2+a)-1\equiv a^2+a \pmod 2
$$
Hence we get
$$
R = (x_R,y_R) = (1,a^2+a)
$$

Comment: Thanks. The question has been answered, it is possible.

Comment: Right, Somos answered first so feel free to accept his solution instead. I just thought it may be interesting to include more examples.

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples listed in the LMFDB.
For exmaple, the
[LMFDB curve $40.a2$](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/40/a/2) 
$\, y^2 = x^3 - 7x - 6\,$  has three integral points
$\, P:= (-1, 0),\;\; Q := (3, 0),\;\; R := (-2,0),\;\;
P\ + Q = R. \,$
All three points have the same $\,y\,$ value $0$. Thus, in answer to your question, for some curves
and for some points it is possible.

Comment: Right. It seems to me that the only solutions have $y=0$, and thus all $2$-division points must be rational over the (unspecified) ground field.

Comment: @Lubin That was my thoughts also which motivated my search of LMFDB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason I did not see it so I apologize for not accepting it.